# Recovering hidden contents from a jpg picture

Tags: forensics, image

Is there any way someone could recover hidden text from a jpg. For example in the picture

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [JPEG artifacts leaking information about redacted contents](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184131/jpeg-artifacts-leaking-information-about-redacted-contents), [How secure is 'blacking out' sensitive information using MS Paint?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126932/how-secure-is-blacking-out-sensitive-information-using-ms-paint)

Comment: What makes you think that there is hidden content in the image? It is probably just a yellow bar and not a yellow bar over something hidden.

Comment: There could be information in others... Thats just an example

Answer (score 1):

The JPEG format has no concept of multiple layers. This means, there can not be any invisible information in the image data itself which somehow can be made visible. It is though possible that meta information contained in the JPEG file still contain information somebody tried to hide. For example an image editor might unknowingly preserve the thumbnail image of the original image (i.e. before the edit) and thus accidentally spill information intended to be hidden.

Comment: Is there some way i can recover the information?

Comment: @Leon: Just search for [extract thumbnail from jpeg](https://www.google.com/search?q=extract++thumbnaiil+from+jpeg) and you'll find many useful hits.