# Is it possible for someone to "peel back" an image layer?

Tags: windows, privacy, image, instagram

I am on a Windows 10 machine using Chrome (latest updates). I took a screenshot of Instagram, because I was having problems logging in, and then using Paint 3D applied a black rectangle to hide my username on the screenshot:

[image: Instagram Screenshot]

My worry is that someone might be able to peel back the black rectangle to reveal my username underneath. I understand that in this instance, my Instagram username is public information, but:

1. Would like to hide the information *in this context*.
2. Also, wanted to check this more generally. If it is indeed possible to peel back image layers applied using software like Paint 3D, is there software that will permanently mask this information irrevocably?

Thanks & hope that this question is appropriate for InfoSec.SE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How secure is 'blacking out' sensitive information using MS Paint?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126932/how-secure-is-blacking-out-sensitive-information-using-ms-paint)

Comment: @Limit Almost. The references there are to Paint. However, I am using Paint 3D which is shipped with my version (and I believe all modern versions) of Win10. Not sure how to get that incremental confirmation for Paint 3D -- here or attempt to ask the responders on that question. Thanks.

Comment: @tchakravarty: The answers there apply here too, specifically the answers around the capabilities of the image formats. You did not provide the format you saved the image in though.